# Setting default parameters to fineUploader

Tags: javascript, fine-uploader

I use a few jquery uploader instances on different pages, where only the callbacks differ. Other options, like 'endpoint', 'multiple' and 'retry', are always the same, but differ from the defaults.

Is there a way to define my own default parameters for the uploader before instantiating it? Or should I add options after the uploader was created?

Answer (score 0):

Simple create an object with your preferred options:

```
var options = {
    request: {
        endpoint: "/my/endpoint"
    },
    ....
};
```

and pass it into as many uploader instances as you want:

```
var uploader = new qq.FineUploader(options);
var uploader2 = new qq.FineUploader(options);
```

Comment: And how do I then change a parameters, e.g. 'callbacks'?

Comment: Simply modify the options object.

Comment: You mean 'before' creating the uploader object, Ray? I was looking for a way alike $.ajaxSetup(). That way, one would only need to parse the options that are different.

But it sure works also as you suggest.